# Probability that independent event with .1 probability occurs after third iteration.

Tags: probability

An airline claims that there is a 0.10 probability that a coach-class ticket holder who flies frequently will be upgraded to first class on any flight. This outcome is independent from flight to flight. Sam is a frequent flier who always purchases coach-class tickets.  What is the probability that Sam’s first upgrade will occur after the third flight?

Since its independent wouldn't it just be 10%
or since its after the third flight would it be  (.9)^3

Comment: The  $.9^3$ is correct. Sam must fail to get upgraded three times in a row.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  in order for MathJax commands to be effective, they must be enclosed in`$` signs.  For example, `$x^2$` shows up as $x^2$.